# My Ubuntu dies over night

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit

It's on 24/7 and sometimes overnight, say once a week, it does this.  The mouse will move, caps lock led toggles, screen still displayed but no click does anything. Pretty soon, clicking and tapping the KB it stops reacting altogether.

I can log in via putty from another PC and if I do 'top' the system appears fine.  I do killall on various things I recognise, one by one, but nothing I have killed so far fixes it.  When I sudo reboot - sometimes it will reboot, but last time it says system going down, but never did.  It always ends the same way, after half hour trying...hold down the off button!  Any suggestions much appreciated cuz I keep loosing my work (I know save it before going home - don't anybody dare say it! Ha,Ha!

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory: 7.9GiB
Processor Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU ES800 @ 3.20GHz x 2
Grpahics: Intel G41 x86/MMX/SSE2
OS Type: 32-bit
Disk 980.2 GB

Cheers - Rich

Comment: Do you have any Nfs or samba shares mounted?

Comment: Save before you go home! :+) There I did say it. 1st thing: check your memory modules. 2nd: check your harddisk health. (aka. make sure this is not hardware related)

Comment: 3. check /var/log/ for errors (probably "syslog" what you want to check)

Comment: My fstab has 3 shares onto windows servers (cifs - if that makes sense?) and 1 share nfs onto a debian box.

There is tons in syslog but nothing obviously an error.  I will check again next time it fails.  A lot of lines starting
Mar  5 07:18:33 RichesPC kernel: [643953.780196] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:0
or
Mar  5 07:36:37 RichesPC kernel: [645037.302974] type=1400 audit(1457163397.465:95): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfi

I will do a hardware check but I need to do a proper full backup before I go down that road so maybe a few days yet.